# Symfony3 - Sonata Admin - I would like to not adding new record but change record

Tags: php, symfony, sonata-admin

I have a little problem. I have entity `Contact` where in is `address`, `phone` and `email` fields . I would like to not adding new records to my database but might change my record in `SonataAdmin`. Probably this is problem with templates in sonata admin bundle.

My services:

```
services:
    admin.contact:
        class: PizzaBundle\Admin\ContactAdmin
        arguments: [~, PizzaBundle\Entity\Contact, ~]
        tags:
            - { name: sonata.admin, manager_type: orm, group: Information, label: Contact }
```

And this is my class `ContactAdmin`:

```
public function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper) {
    $formMapper
        ->with('Contact', array(
            'class'       => 'col-md-8',
            'box_class'   => 'box box-solid box-success',
            'description' => 'Change your contact'))
        ->add('address', 'text')
        ->add('phone', 'text')
        ->add('email', 'text')
        ->end();
}

protected function configureDatagridFilters(DatagridMapper $datagridMapper)
{
    $datagridMapper
        ->add('address')
        ->add('phone')
        ->add('email')
    ;
}

protected function configureListFields(ListMapper $listMapper)
{
    $listMapper
        ->addIdentifier('address')
        ->addIdentifier('phone')
        ->addIdentifier('email')
    ;
}
```

Help me please :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might need activate the security system from Symfony/SonataAdmin and make sure to deny (i.e. no set) these permissions to the user, later Sonata is able to hide this action in you admin automatically.

Here explains how to do that using roles or acl: https://sonata-project.org/bundles/admin/master/doc/reference/security.html#security-handlers